# How can I prevent the signal and 3G icon from turning it to white icon when my connection to Google server is lost?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have a limited plan for mobile data usage(only 100MB per mounth) so I use mobile data for sending/recieving MMSes and for browsing only. I have mobile data turned off 99% of time. White signal bars are hard to see, so I would like to know, if there is any way to turn the "icons goes white while not connected to Google servers" funtcion off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit your `Framework-Res.apk`. 
Its a bit complicated and differenct on every phone. So I can't simply provide a guide.

But I suggest you, to ask in your phone forum on [xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com).

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to tell you to find a theme where the "not connected to Google" bars are painted the same color as the connected bars.  Of course that only works if you have a theme manager on your phone and can find one you like.

Or hell, make one.